# Pass token with ssr redirect

Tags: authentication, next.js, next-auth

I am using NextAuth and I need to sign out the user within the ssr method `getServerSideProps`. To achieve this I am simply returning a redirect to the NextAuth signout URL. This works fine except I want the user to signout automatically without opening the fallback NextAuth signout page.

```
    return {
      redirect: {
        permanent: false,
        destination: "/api/auth/signout"
      }
    }
```

So I tried to pass in the csrftoken but I am not sure how to set it to the body in the nextjs redirect context. e.g.

```
const csrfToken = await getCsrfToken({ req })
   
     return {
          redirect: {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: csrfToken,
            permanent: false,
            destination: "/api/auth/signout"
          }
        }
```

How should I pass in the csrfToken in the redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot pass headers with `redirect`. this is its type:

```
export type Redirect =
  | {
      statusCode: 301 | 302 | 303 | 307 | 308
      destination: string
      basePath?: false
    }
  | {
      permanent: boolean
      destination: string
      basePath?: false
    }
```

you can use `context.res.writeHead`

```
ServerResponse<IncomingMessage>.writeHead(statusCode: number, statusMessage?: string | undefined, headers?: OutgoingHttpHeaders | OutgoingHttpHeader[] | undefined): ServerResponse<IncomingMessage>
```